# Haml and Sass for Programmer's Notepad?

Tags: haml, sass, programmers-notepad

Does anyone know where I can find some cool syntax highlighting for Haml and/or Sass for the Programmer's Notepad?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [issue 224](http://code.google.com/p/pnotepad/issues/detail?id=224), syntax highlighting has been added for HAML and SASS.